# Диаграмма Ганта

Tags: javascript, xml

Пытаюсь использовать для построения диаграммы скрипт `jsgantt`, с помощью файла XML пытаюсь подгрузить данные, но браузер файл не видит, подскажите в чем проблема может быть:

Скрипт:

```
// here's all the html code neccessary to display the chart object
// Future idea would be to allow XML file name to be passed in and chart tasks built from file.

var g = new JSGantt.GanttChart('g',document.getElementById('GanttChartDIV'), 'day');

g.setShowRes(1); // Show/Hide Responsible (0/1)
g.setShowDur(1); // Show/Hide Duration (0/1)
g.setShowComp(1); // Show/Hide % Complete(0/1)
g.setCaptionType('Resource');  // Set to Show Caption (None,Caption,Resource,Duration,Complete)
if( g ) {
  // Parameters (pID, pName, pStart, pEnd, pColor, pLink, pMile, pRes,  pComp, pGroup, pParent, pOpen)
  // use the XML file parser 
  JSGantt.parseXML('../project.xml',g)
  g.Draw(); 
  g.DrawDependencies();
} else {
  alert("not defined");
}
```

XML:

```
<task>
    <pID>10</pID>
    <pName>WCF Changes</pName>
    <pStart></pStart>
    <pEnd></pEnd>
    <pColor>0000ff</pColor>
    <pLink></pLink>
    <pMile>0</pMile>
    <pRes></pRes>
    <pComp>0</pComp>
    <pGroup>1</pGroup>
    <pParent>0</pParent>
    <pOpen>1</pOpen>
    <pDepend></pDepend>
    <pCaption>Brian</pCaption>
</task>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас JS файл выполняется на клиенте, а XML лежит на сервере. Поэтому строка

```
 JSGantt.parseXML('../project.xml',g)
```

бессмысленна. Нужно писать так

```
 JSGantt.parseXML('/path-to-xml/project.xml',g)
```

где path-to-xml путь к XML на веб-сервере

Т.е. если JS файл у Вас доступен по адресу `http://myhost.com/path/scripts/myscript.js` то Вам нужно написать

```
 JSGantt.parseXML('/path/project.xml',g)
```

Если же XML у Вас лежит в той же папке, что и html, то просто пишите

```
 JSGantt.parseXML('project.xml',g)
```

Comment: так -  `JSGantt.parseXML('/D:\work\diagramm\jsgantt_v12/project.xml',g);`?

Comment: @СергейНиконенко Нет. Доуточнил ответ

Comment: у меня и скрипт и файл лежат по адресу - `D:\work\diagramm\jsgantt_v12`

Comment: @СергейНиконенко У Вас веб-сервер запущен? html-файл какой-то есть? Откуда вы его запускаете? Прямо из проводника или вводя адрес в браузер?

Comment: html страница в архиве с скриптом была, запускаю прям с папки, веб-сервер не запущен

Comment: @СергейНиконенко Я правильно понимаю, что у Вас html и js файлы лежат в одной папке, а xml на одну папку выше?

Comment: нет, все файлы в одной папке

Comment: @СергейНиконенко Так тогда зачем Вы морочили голову с вашим `'../project.xml`? Просто пишите `project.xml`

Comment: так тоже ошибка - Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Comment: хм, в мазиле все показывает нормально, а вот в хроме нет, еще пишет в хроме -  `XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///D:/work/diagramm/jsgantt_v12/project.xml. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https`

Comment: @СергейНиконенко Не может хром послать аякс запрос к файловой системе. Политики безопасности не позволяют. Ставьте веб-сервер и все будет работать

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь.